# How to assign object to component when bootstrap?

Tags: dart, angular

I am newcomer of angular2. I want to know how to pass an object reference to components when they are boostrap() in main.dart? 
In this case, I want to pass the EventBus object instance to each components.

```
import 'package:angular2/bootstrap.dart';
import 'package:myproject/component/component.dart';
import 'package:event_bus/event_bus.dart';

main() {
   EventBus eventbus = new EventBus();
   bootstrap(Navbar);
}

part of myproject.component;

@Component(selector: '[navbar]', templateUrl: 'navbar.html')
class Navbar {
   EventBus eventbus;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
maiin()
   bootstrap(Navbar, [EventBus]);
}

@Component(selector: '[navbar]', templateUrl: 'navbar.html')
class Navbar {
   constructor(private eventBus:EventBus);
}
```

is all you need and Angular2 takes cate of the rest.